# Laravel - How to return data from two repositories

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to return two methods at once in the find function

```
public function find($id)
{  
    return AddRepository::findOrFail($id) && 
    AddMeRepository::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: This yells [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) so hard. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to return data from both repositories but i can only manage to do one

Comment: Return an array with 2 items, one for the first repository and one for the second

Comment: So save the results in two variables and then return an array containing the two variables. Or create a Data Transfer Object, but the idea is the same.

Comment: What would you expect the returned value to look like if this had worked? Follow that thought process through.

Comment: No php method can return more than object / variable. Return them as an array: return [ 'addrepo' => AddRepository::findOrFail($id), 'addmerepo' => AddMeRepository....

Answer (score 1):

```
public function find($id)
{  
    var result = [];
    result['addRepository'] = AddRepository::findOrFail($id);
    result['addMeRepository'] =AddMeRepository::findOrFail($id);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function find($id)
{  
    return array(AddRepository::findOrFail($id) ,AddMeRepository::findOrFail($id));
}
```

when you call method

```
 list($add,$addme)=YourClass::find($id);
```

you can use $add and $addme variables.